# Cannot query with PHP PDO a saved query in MS Access Database

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

I have a Microsoft Access database with a bunch of saved queries. I would like to use PHP to run and grab the results of these queries. I can query tables in the same database just fine. My understanding is that I can treat queries as if they were tables.

This will return data from the table "New Grower Fields" just fine:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$connString; SystemDB=$mdw; Uid=$username; Pwd=$password");
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM [New Grower Fields]");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
```

But if I want to use a saved query, which I *believe* should act just like querying a table, I don't get anything.

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$connString; SystemDB=$mdw; Uid=$username; Pwd=$password");
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM [Daily Tonnage by Plant]");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
```

Is there any way to allow me to get the results of a saved query in MS Access with PHP? I'm fairly new to this. I appreciate any and all help! I will be happy to provide any additional information needed.

Comment: OK first up, a bit of general advice, don't put spaces in object names in an access db. Secondly there is no reason why that wouldn't work as long as you have permission to access the query (and you spelled it right, of course) - just as a quick sanity check I've just tested it on my own system and I can indeed retrieve records from queries in exactly the same way as I can from tables. Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` as the second line and see if it spits out a useful error message.

Comment: @DaveRandom I unfortunately have no control over the access db; I can only read. I tried your suggestion and it gave me the error msg: "PDOException: SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) in C:\wamp\www\getDataGL.php on line 5." Line 5 being `$sth->execute();`. I'll continue searching, but I'm not entirely sure what that means.

Comment: @DaveRandom You know what? I just tried it with a different saved query and it worked fine. Here is the SQL from the query that errors: `SELECT [collect plant and date for reports].plant, [collect plant and date for reports].[Grade Date], Sum([NetWt]/2000) AS NetTon, Sum([NetWt]*[Perc1]/2000) AS Ton1, Sum([NetWt]*[Perc2S]/2000) AS Ton2S, Sum([NetWt]*[Perc3]/2000) AS Ton3, Sum([NetWt]*[PercCull]/2000) AS TonCull, Sum([NetWt]*[Perc2O]/2000) AS Ton2O
FROM [collect plant and date for reports]
GROUP BY [collect plant and date for reports].plant, [collect plant and date for reports].[Grade Date];`

Comment: OK it sounds like the query is expecting user input when it's run in Access and this is much more difficult to diagnose without actually having the file. What happens if you run the query in Access? Does it prompt you for a value before showing you the results? If so, what is the message displayed in the prompt - it should tell you the field name. Can you show the column list from the (horribly named) `collect plant and date for reports` table?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. We use a remote desktop connection to open our database upon connection like this: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\msaccess.exe" "\\server\path\Grower Loads\Live2012\Converted_GrowerScheduling.mdb" /wrkgrp \\server\path\etc\NETWORKGRP.mdw /cmd Toledo`.  My connection string is `"odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=\\\\server\\path\\Grower Loads\\Live2012\\Converted_GrowerScheduling.mdb; SystemDB=\\\\server\\path\\etc\\NETWORKGRP.mdw;Uid=$name;Pwd=$pwd"`The **/cmd Toledo** is the important part, need to put in connection string somehow?

Comment: If I load the terminal server without the **/cmd Toledo** at the end, the query does not work. We use that command to specify what facility they're "working" in. This led me to believe this is the parameter it wants, but I have no idea how to send it, or if it's even possible. I may have to get a new query created that goes about this a different way.

Comment: Is `[collect plant and date for reports]` also a query, not a table? The `/cmd` switch passes and argument that would be returned by the `Command()` function, which is not used in the above query. AFAIK there is no way to mimic this behaviour via ODBC, you would need to run the raw query and pass the string `Toledo` manually. Can you get enough access to the database to view the `[collect plant and date for reports]` object and, if it is indeed a query, extract the SQL? If you can, make sure you get the SQL of any other query objects it uses as well.

Comment: I got access and looked around. `collect plant and date for reports` queries another query, which queried ANOTHER that no one had told me about (which actually has more relevant data), and I can connect to with my PHP just fine. Thanks for pushing me to look deeper! You've made this a lot easier. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Don't forget you can always just run the actual query against the tables, Access SQL is not as limited as people think it's just that sometimes you have to go the very long way round. Also don't try getting clever by using functions from VBA global modules in SQL, they won't work over ODBC. When I first picked up Access SQL having come from MySQL I was filled with dread, but it's actually not that bad once you get used to it. I won't be switching to using Access for my applications or anything, but at least I now understand (sort of) how it works.

Comment: Also note that you should *always* `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` regardless of RDBMS, and/or whether you are having any problems with it. IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to solve it for me:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$connString; SystemDB=$mdw; Uid=$username; Pwd=$password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT [Grade Date], NetWt FROM [Daily Tonnage by Plant]");
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

I added
`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and changed

`$results = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`